# Pass data from _app's getServerSideProps to pages' getServerSideProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is there a way to pass data from `_app`'s `getServerSideProps` to page's `getServerSideProps`?
My issue is as follows:
I have a custom _app with `getServerSideProps`. Here I check if the user is authenticated and if so, load the user from DB. Both (isAuthenticated and user) are then passed to the _app's props.

Then I have actual pages. Some of these pages are public and some need authorization, so they have their own `getServerSideProps`. I would like to access the user data loaded in _app's `getServerSideProps` from within the specific pages' `getServerSideProps` in order to decide if a redirect should take place. Otherwise, I'd have to load the user info twice - first on the _app level and then on the page level.

Is there a way to load the data only once (on the _app level) and reuse it on the page level?

```js
// pages/_app.jsx

const App = ...

App.getServerSideProps = async(context) => {
    let isAuthenticated = false;
    let user = {};

    if (context?.req) {
        // get token from Cookies, validate token & load user
    }

    return {
        props: { isAuthenticated, user },
    }
}
```

```js
// pages/profile.jsx

const ProfilePage = ...

ProfilePage.getServerSideProps = async(context) => {
    // get token, load user - in this step, I'd like to reuse the previously loaded data

    if (!isAuthenticated || !user.HAS_SOME_SPECIFIC_PERMISSION) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/login',
            },
        }
    }

    return { props: {} }
}
```

### Edit

Before I finished writing this question, I already decided to get rid of my own auth and use NextAuth.js. However, while I no longer need an answer to this question, it still seems like an interesting "mental exercise" question, so I'm leaving it here... in case anybody needs to pass data from top level `getServerSideProps` to page level `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: `_app` does not support `getServerSideProps`, that code won't work. See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app#caveats.

Comment: Also, using `ProfilePage.getServerSideProps` in a page is not the proper way to use `getServerSideProps`. `getServerSideProps` needs to be a named export, e.g. `export async function getServerSideProps(context) { ... }`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props.

Comment: @juliomalves Yeah, you're right. In my first draft I used `getInitialProps` on the _app level and the second draft never saw the light of runtime.. 
All in all, the question seems mute. Still though, just out of curiosity, would it be somehow possible to pass data from _app `getInitialProps` to page's `getServerSideProps `? (I guess not, but who knows..)

Comment: No, it wouldn't be possible to do so either.